# How to grep file containing some binary characters?

Tags: linux, grep

One application sometimes, not very often, puts some incorrect (binary) characters in log. Only information that it matches is printed, no matched lines.

```
$ grep -e error app.log 
Binary file app.log matches
```

How can I grep the log simply omitting the binary characters?

`less` handles the file correctly, prints the binary characters as some escape sequences, so maybe some pipe `less` to `grep` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell `grep` to interpret the source file as a text file:

```
grep -a -e error app.log
```

Take into account that `grep` will not escape the binary characters so you should pipe the output to `less` or `od -c` to prevent possible negative effects of the characters to the terminal.